# how to use assert method for webservice class?

Tags: unit-test

Yea I am trying to implement the same code as kiran said.,But I just want to know that if EchostringResult is of some other type say integer,with integer data's defined..then how can we use assert for such type?I know its a silly question.I am quiet new to salesforce.Please bear..

```
//Generated by wsdl2apex

public class docSample {
    public class EchoStringResponse_element {
        public String EchoStringResult;
        private String[] EchoStringResult_type_info = new String[]{
                            'EchoStringResult',
                            'http://doc.sample.com/docSample',
                             null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{
                             'http://doc.sample.com/docSample',
                             'true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{
                             'EchoStringResult'};
    }
    public class EchoString_element {
        public String input;
        private String[] input_type_info = new String[]{
                              'input',
                              'http://doc.sample.com/docSample',
                               null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{
                               'http://doc.sample.com/docSample',
                               'true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'input'};
    }
    public class DocSamplePort {
        public String endpoint_x = 'http://YourServer/YourService';
        public Map<String,String> inputHttpHeaders_x;
        public Map<String,String> outputHttpHeaders_x;
        public String clientCertName_x;
        public String clientCert_x;
        public String clientCertPasswd_x;
        public Integer timeout_x;
        private String[] ns_map_type_info = new String[]{
                          'http://doc.sample.com/docSample', 'docSample'};
        public String EchoString(String input) {
            docSample.EchoString_element request_x = new 
                                           docSample.EchoString_element();
            request_x.input = input;
            docSample.EchoStringResponse_element response_x;
            Map<String, docSample.EchoStringResponse_element> response_map_x = 
                       new Map<String, docSample.EchoStringResponse_element>();
            response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
            WebServiceCallout.invoke(
              this,
              request_x,
              response_map_x,
              new String[]{endpoint_x,
              'urn:dotnet.callouttest.soap.sforce.com/EchoString',
              'http://doc.sample.com/docSample',
              'EchoString',
              'http://doc.sample.com/docSample',
              'EchoStringResponse',
              'docSample.EchoStringResponse_element'}
            );
            response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
            return response_x.EchoStringResult;
        }
    }
}

    @isTest
global class WebServiceMockImpl implements WebServiceMock {
   global void doInvoke(
           Object stub,
           Object request,
           Map<String, Object> response,
           String endpoint,
           String soapAction,
           String requestName,
           String responseNS,
           String responseName,
           String responseType) {
       docSample.EchoStringResponse_element respElement = 
           new docSample.EchoStringResponse_element();
       respElement.EchoStringResult = Integer values defined;
       response.put('response_x', respElement); 
   }
}


private class WebSvcCalloutTest {
    @isTest static void testEchoString() {              
        Test.setMock(WebServiceMock.class, new WebServiceMockImpl());

        String output = WebSvcCallout.callEchoString(integer value);

        System.assertEquals(?); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us more code to understand exactly what you want to test? We're having to make a lot of assumptions here. What does WebSvcCallout.callweb() return? The body of the HTTP response? the payload? Is it a JSON payload?

Comment: yes,it will provide the response. and it is of custom type list method..say,method--> public webout[] callweb() and declared as public List<webout> lst;

Comment: Please post full code; otherwise we can only answer in generalities. It is important to know what your method does with the response from the webservice? Since you cannot make actual web service calls from test methods, what you test is the manipulation that your method does with the result of the call. Unless all you want to achieve is test coverage for your code without doing any assertions (which is bad practice)?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the example you are using is from this reference:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_wsdl2apex_testing.htm
You would be creating mock by below way. Altering some code so that you would be able to control on which output you want to assert.

```
@isTest
global class WebServiceMockImpl implements WebServiceMock {
   global String mockResponseString;
   global WebServiceMock(String mockResponseString){
         this.mockResponseString= mockResponseString;
   }
   global void doInvoke(
           Object stub,
           Object request,
           Map<String, Object> response,
           String endpoint,
           String soapAction,
           String requestName,
           String responseNS,
           String responseName,
           String responseType) {
       docSample.EchoStringResponse_element respElement = 
           new docSample.EchoStringResponse_element();
       respElement.EchoStringResult = mockResponseString;
       response.put('response_x', respElement); 
   }
}
```

You can make assertion in below way:

```
@isTest
private class WebSvcCalloutTest {
    @isTest static void testEchoString() {              
        // This causes a fake response to be generated
        String mockResponseString = 'Here goes the response that you expect.';
        Test.setMock(WebServiceMock.class, new WebServiceMockImpl(mockResponseString ));

        // Call the method that invokes a callout
        String output = WebSvcCallout.callEchoString('Hello World!');

        // Verify that a fake result is returned
        System.assertEquals(mockResponseString , output); 
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: But that's for string

Comment: I want the same to be executed for val..

Comment: I have passed mockresponsestring you can pass which is going to be your output and then you can assert on it.

Comment: What is it that you want to test with this? It looks like this test only covers your mock, which is a bit pointless.

Comment: @mkorman This has provided a way by which you can generate different output by setting different output for different scenarios. Let's say you are getting students data as json string then by this can simulate such response and test your dependent code which comes after calling. Even you can generate invalid json and test exception handling code.

Comment: @mkorman as I stated in the solution pri is using code from sales force reference. You can check that.

Comment: The issue is that the question does not have enough information. We have to guess what the user wants to do. I don't think that the question can be answered until the OP tells us what he wants to test: the web service itself or the code that reasons with the results of the web service. Unfortunately, the suggested answer seems to test neither.

Comment: Agreed this can solved once we check what actually pri wants to achieve

Comment: It will provide the response. and it is of custom type list method..say,method--> public webout[] callweb() and declared as public List<webout> lst;

Comment: its of list type not string type